# want to fetch first 9 records and make one more record which will be as “Others” in mysql

Tags: php, sql, mysql, zend-framework, stored-procedures

I am fetching records from one table with count of one field with other field as name. I want only 10 records. out of which 9 records give me field and its count. but i want to show 10 record as "Others" with all remaining fields with count. This is something like wrapping records.

Something like below will be table contents.

> emp_id | designation
>
> 1   |   software Engg.
>
> 2   |   software Engg.
>
> 3   |   Project Manager

not less than 10 designation.

And I want to show first 10 records as

```
Software Engineers  20
Project Manager     5
....
....
....
Others    50
```

Is there any way to make SQL Query for mysql db. So that it will be fast and save time in application level where I am adding up record counts for "Others". Or Suggest me how I can make it possible in effective way.

Comment: Can you just do a standard `SELECT .. GROUP BY` and then a `UNION SELECT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT IF(rowNum <= 9, designation, 'Other') designation, SUM(cnt)
FROM (SELECT designation, COUNT(*) cnt, (@row := @row + 1) rowNum
    FROM contents, (SELECT @row := 0) dm
    GROUP BY designation
    ORDER BY designation
) d
GROUP BY IF(rowNum <= 9, designation, 'Other')
```

Change the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` however you decide what 9 to show.

Comment: .. I m getting error as "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: @kamlesh-bhure Updated.. Sorry about that

Comment: ...  Yes it works .. can you share whats the logic behind the above query. Will this query work fast on 10000 records?

Comment: This is perfect answer. I am creating stored procedure for this and this will work fast.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` option in your query which will tell MySQL to count total number of rows disregarding LIMIT clause. You still need to execute a second query in order to retrieve row count, but it’s a simple query and not as complex as your query which retrieved the data.

Usage is pretty simple. In you main query you need to add SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS option just after SELECT and in second query you need to use `FOUND_ROWS()` function to get total number of rows. Queries would look like this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS name, email FROM users WHERE name LIKE 'a%' LIMIT 10;

SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Comment: thanks ... it works... I can use it to get count of employees by providing LIMIT 9, no of  found rows.

Comment: this doesn't solve my problem completely. becoz i m writing query select designation, count(distinct emp_id) from emp_design Limit 9, $num_rows;  but it gives me zero records.